# Entity Framework: Linq where clause compare date and time value with seconds difference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, azure-sql-database

```
var onLineP = (from od in db.RTLS_ONLINEPERSONSTATUS
               where (lsdAts <= od.created_time && od.created_time <= DateTime.Now)
               select od).ToList();
```

In the above query i am getting records of previous days but not current day. I am using Entity framework as my orm and azure-sql as back-end. RTLS_ONLINEPERSONSTATUS table has two records with ***created times 4/17/2017 10:00:09 AM, 4/18/2017 10:00:09 AM*** as respectively. I am getting record with ***created time value = 4/17/2017 10:00:09 AM*** and not getting ***current day(4/18/2017 10:00:09 AM)*** record. lsdAts(last sync date at server) = {4/6/2017 10:34:09 AM}.

Comment: what is lsdAts?

Comment: Print `DateTime.Now` to make sure you compare times with the same time zones.

Comment: lsdAts(last sync date at server) = {4/6/2017 10:34:09 AM}

Comment: I am getting DateTime.Now = {4/18/2017 11:06:47 AM}

Comment: Can you print `db.RTLS_ONLINEPERSONSTATUS` content before the query? Because I tried the comparison and I see that it compares also seconds.

Comment: When i comment where condition  i am getting the two records, without commenting it giving me only one records as i stated in my problem statement. Thank u KernelMode for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution for my problem. The hidden problem is that my sql server is at south-Acia and i am accessing it from south-India, so time zones are mismatching because Linq converting Datetime.Now into SysDateTime() at runtime. To overcome this i had added 330 minutes(that is 5 hours 30 minutes) to the Datetime.Now as shown in below code snippet.

```
  var onLineP = (from od in db.RTLS_ONLINEPERSONSTATUS
                where (lsdAts <= od.created_time && od.created_time <= DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now, 330))
                                           select od).ToList();
```

Comment: This will fail if daylight saving times don't start and end on exactly the same day. I suspect they don't, you are on different hemispheres.

Comment: yeah i know, when it will fails exactly but, as per my requirement it is sufficient since my system is going to be operated in india only. But i need to know best practices in dealing with times.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, it is related to time zone differences. I suggest to use UTC only when comparing times. It means also to keep the time in the database in UTC also. Eventually the code should look like that:

```
  var onLineP = (from od in db.RTLS_ONLINEPERSONSTATUS
  where (lsdAts <= od.created_time_utc && od.created_time_utc <= DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime())
  select od).ToList();
```